# Image masking using quartz2d and multiple images

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, core-image

Hi I'm trying to mask one image with another to leave just the differences between the two images.

Quartz2D seems to have an appropriate method to do this called CGImageCreateWithMask, which so far as I can tell should return the result of the original image being masked with the mask which is a CGImageRef so can be either a mask or another image.

Unfortunately all I seem to be getting back from this method is null. The documentation says something about the mask needing to be in the deviceGray colourspace which I am a little unsure about and may be causing some of my problems.

```
    CGImageRef initialImage = [imageContext createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
    CGImageRef alteredImage = [imageContext createCGImage:[[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bun1red"]] fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
    CGImageRef maskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(initialImage, alteredImage);

    _myUIImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImage];
```

If I replace maskedImage in the last line with either of the other two they both display correctly. But maskedImage seems to be null.

I don't particularly want to have to resort doing an xOR on the individual pixels or something similar if I can avoid it.

So if anybody knows how to use this method correctly or what i am doing wrong, some pointers would be greatly appreciated.